# Add new row doesn't show when binding to List<>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-6

I have a small problem in understanding why this happens and how it can be avoided.
I have a code first EF. I have 1 entity. Just for the sake of simplicity. Next piece of code explains how I add List to DataSource of datagirdView.

```
using (var db = new Models.DevExContext())
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Persons.ToList();
}
```

Add new row doesn't show. Why is this?

If I add all these records to BindingList and add that list as DataSource everything works fine.

```
using (var db = new Models.DevExContext())
{
    BindingList<Person> persons = new BindingList<Person>();
    db.Persons.ToList().ForEach(x => persons .Add(x));
    dataGridView1.DataSource = persons ;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite certain if i understand you correctly. You do realise that `.ToList()` creates a copy of the list and adding an element to `db.tOsobas` will not add the element to the copy? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I am not adding an element to the List. I do not have add new row displayed at all. It's as if I cannot add to the list at all or type in the list doesn't have parametreless constructor.